# Hide an element forever on hover

Tags: hover

When someone hover my site title, the background changes forever, I want the title to disappear forever too.

```
<h1 onmouseover="changeBodyBackground()">{Title}</h1>

function changeBodyBackground() {
document.body.style.background = "url(http://i.imgur.com/EyWVWO7.gif)";
document.body.style.backgroundSize = "Cover";
}
```

The code is the background html and javascript, I want to remove the title (h1).

Answer (score 0):

Assign and ID

```
<h1 id="title" onmouseover="changeBodyBackground()">{Title}</h1>
```

At the end of the JavaScript function

```
 document.getElementById('title').style.display = 'none';
```